# Custom Post Type has_archive

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-post-type-archives

I have the following code in my functions.php file:-

```
/**
 *  Register Add Job
 *
 */

add_action( 'init', 'rv_jobs_cpt' );
function rv_jobs_cpt() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'               => _x( 'Jobs', 'post type general name', 'engwp' ),
        'singular_name'      => _x( 'Jobs', 'post type singular name', 'engwp' ),
        'menu_name'          => _x( 'Jobs', 'admin menu', 'engwp' ),
        'name_admin_bar'     => _x( 'Jobs', 'add new on admin bar', 'engwp' ),
        'add_new'            => _x( 'Add New Job', 'Property', 'engwp' ),
        'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New Job', 'engwp' ),
        'new_item'           => __( 'New Job', 'engwp' ),
        'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit Job', 'engwp' ),
        'view_item'          => __( 'View Jobs', 'engwp' ),
        'all_items'          => __( 'All Jobs', 'engwp' ),
        'search_items'       => __( 'Search Jobs', 'engwp' ),
        'parent_item_colon'  => __( 'Parent Jobs:', 'engwp' ),
        'not_found'          => __( 'No Jobs found.', 'engwp' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No Jobs found in Trash.', 'engwp' )
    );

    $args = array(
        'description'         => __( 'Jobs', 'engwp' ),
        'labels'          => $labels,
        'supports'        => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'trackbacks', 'custom-fields', 'comments', 'revisions' ),
        'hierarchical'          => true,
        'public'            => true,
        'publicly_queryable'    => true,
        'query_var'         => true, 
        'show_ui'           => true,
        'menu_icon'         => 'dashicons-universal-access-alt',
        'show_ui'             => true,
        'show_in_menu'          => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'show_in_admin_bar' => true,
        'menu_position' => 31,
        'can_export'        => true,
        'has_archive' => 'jobs/[^/]+/[^/]+',
        'exclude_from_search'   => false,
        'capability_type'   => 'post',
        'taxonomies'          => array( 'category' ),
    );

    register_post_type( 'jobs', $args );

}
```

I've added `'has_archive' => 'jobs/[^/]+/[^/]+',` as I want to show the archive-jobs.php if you were on `website.com/jobs`, `website.com/jobs/value` and `website.com/jobs/value/value2`

With the above code, I can access the jobs by going to `website.com/jobs/value/value2` but not when I go to `website.com/jobs/value`.

Is there a way to get both URL's working?

If I change `has_archive` to `'has_archive' => 'jobs/[^/]+/[^/]+',` it will work the opposite way around, so `website.com/jobs/value` would work and `website.com/jobs/value/value2` wouldn't.

Please advise.